# How to SELECT only the most recent of each group using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
TABLE sales
| id | name | date       | amount |
|----|------|------------|--------|
|  1 | Mike | 2016-12-05 |  67.15 |
|  2 | Mike | 2016-12-09 |  98.24 |
|  3 | John | 2016-12-12 |  12.98 |
|  4 | Mike | 2016-12-19 |  78.48 |
|  5 | Will | 2016-12-19 | 175.26 |
|  6 | John | 2016-12-22 |  14.26 |
|  7 | John | 2016-12-23 |  13.48 |
```

I am trying to create a view that will group by the name column and return only the most resent amount. It should look like this:

```
TABLE sales_view
| id | name | date       | amount |
|----|------|------------|--------|
|  4 | Mike | 2016-12-19 |  78.48 |
|  5 | Will | 2016-12-19 | 175.26 |
|  7 | John | 2016-12-23 |  13.48 |
```

I'm not sure how to go about making this. I would imagine I would need sub-queries, but I know that SQL get mad if you try to use them inside of views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tuple and a subquery with group by for max(date)

```
 select * from sales
 where (name, date) in ( select name, max(date) 
                         from sales 
                         group by name)
```

Comment: That actually worked and SQL didn't yell at me for using a sub-query inside of the view. Thank you.

Comment: I will. It just makes me wait 10 minutes before I can mark it.